# $RSA$ cryptosystem with $e=2$

Tags: cryptography

There exists a $RSA$ cryptosystem with $e=2$ , where $e$ is the encryption exponent ?(In general $e>2$)

Comment: What is required from an RSA exponent for the decryption to work (for the legitimate reader who knows the private key)? How does that help here?

Comment: The relation  gcd(e,phi(n))=1 is useful just for encryption?

Comment: Correct. A good start! What do you know about $\phi(n)$?

Comment: n=p*q , p,q primes .So phi(n)=(p-1)*(q-1).

Comment: Correct again. What can you say about $p$ and $q$, if $\gcd(2,(p-1)(q-1))=1$?

Comment: Then p=q=2.Actually I have to apply  in a numerical problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The encryption exponent $e$ should meet the condition
$$
1=\gcd(e,\phi(n))=\gcd(e,(p-1)(q-1)).
$$
In RSA the primes $p,q$ are distinct, so at least one of them is odd (in all useful cases both are). Therefore the encryption exponent $e$ can never be an even integer.

Comment: Why must `e` meet this condition? I'm looking for an answer, but I cannot find it anywhere. I would appreciate a hint. Thanks!

Comment: @Patrick Otherwise decryption will not be injective. Distinct plaintexts would share the same ciphertext. This is undesirable.

Comment: Thank you! In the meantime I also found another post titled as [Why in RSA, the public exponent  must be coprime with ()](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1221723/why-in-rsa-the-public-exponent-e-must-be-coprime-with-phi-n?rq=1) about that.

Comment: That's a good find, @Patrick. Well done.

Answer (score 2):

The basic system where $n=pq$,$p,q$ distinct primes, $1 < x < n$ is some message, and $x^2 (n)$ is used as the ciphertext, is called [the Rabin cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin_cryptosystem). This is *not* RSA, because in RSA the secret key is the exponent $d$, but for $e=2$ no valid $d$ can be found (see Jyrki's answer). For Rabin we need to know $p$ and $q$ to perform a square root on the ciphertext, but then we get (almost always) $4$ possible messages $x$, so decryption is ambiguous.

Of course, in practice we use padding on $x$ to ensure only one of the 4 candidates obeys the padding rules (and encryption is randomised, and always "big" w.r.t. $n$, just like we do in RSA in practice). See the linked page for details on decryption (i.e. to find the 4 candidates). AFAIK no standard system has been agreed upon, the system never became even remotely as popular as RSA.

It's mostly of theoretical interest: getting the message $x$ from the ciphertext $x^2 (n)$ is provably as hard as factoring $n$, and this has not been proved for RSA.

Comment: Actually my problem is:Alice wants to send the message $m$-a natural number , $m<8$ to Bob.She encrypts the message $9*m$ using a "version" of the $RSA$ cryptosystem with  the exponent  of encryption $e=2$.We suppose that Bob has the private  key $p=7$ , $q=11$.How can decrypt Bob the message  $c=23$ received  from Alice?

Comment: @matt You should have asked that instead.... Compute the square roots of $23$ modulo 77 (using the link I gave you), you get 10, 32, 45, 67 (check!). Multiply these with the inverse of 9 modulo 77 (which is 60, check!)  to get possible $m$ values, only one of them is $< 8$.

Comment: Why you compute the inverse of 9 modulo 77?Why not the inverse of 81 modulo 77?

Comment: @matt After the square root we have $9m$.

Comment: Thank you!I am sorry but I am  begginer..